# What is the analogue of the Jacobi theta function in the Weyl representation?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-functions, heisenberg-groups

It is known (see for example [the associated Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_representation)) that the Jacobi theta function
$$\vartheta(z; \tau) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \exp(\pi in^2\tau + 2\pi inz)$$
arises from a certain representation of the Heisenberg group $H_3(\mathbb{R})$. Namely, we take the theta representation of $H_3(\mathbb{R})$, and look at the action of the discrete subgroup $H_3(\mathbb{Z})$. Then $\vartheta$ is invariant under this action.

By Stone–von Neumann, the theta representation is isomorphic to the Weyl representation of the Heisenberg group on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This seems to imply that there should be a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ analogous to the Jacobi theta function. Using the Segal–Bargmann transform, one can try calculating the corresponding function explicitly, but the integrals involved seem to get very messy.

**Question.** Is there any short, explicit description of the function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ corresponding to $z\mapsto \vartheta(z;\tau)$?

Comment: @LSpice The Wikipedia page linked to by the OP says Weyl rather than Weil. The Weil representation is a representation of the metaplectic group, while the Weyl representation is a representation of the Heisenberg group.

Comment: @LSpice As the other commenter suggests, I did intend Weyl (I edited it back); the Weil representation is a closely related object, though, so no worries!

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, thanks; and, @‍MichaelBarz, I apologise for my wrong edit.  I will delete my original comment.

Comment: There can't be such a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, since a translation operator (e.g. $T$ defined by $(Tf)(x) = f(x-1)$ has no eigenvectors in  $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ .

Comment: @jjcale I am confused now. There is an isomorphism between these two representations, right? The theta function is an element of the theta representation, under this isomorphism it must go to some element of the Weyl representation, no?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე No, the theta function is invariant under a discrete subgroup of the Heisenberg group, this is not possible for functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ .

Comment: @jjcale So then the theta function does not belong to the space ${\mathcal H}_\tau$? That is, it does not have finite norm as defined in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_representation#Hilbert_space)?

Comment: Yes, the theta function has infinite norm, because $exp(-2\pi y^2 / Im \tau) \mid \theta(z)\mid^2$ is double periodic for $z \rightarrow z+1$ and $z \rightarrow z + \tau$

Comment: @jjcale Oh I see now. Don't you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the element you're seeking is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Rather, it is a distribution (aka generalized function) that acts on Schwarz functions.
Since you know it has to be invariant by $H_3(\mathbb{Z})$, and unique up to scale, it is immediate to verify that the answer is the Dirac comb: a $\delta$-function at each integer.